# What are the current views of the Catholic Church on the right to secession?

Tags: catholicism, civil-government, morality, authority

I’ve recently heard an interesting opinion that no entity has moral right to exercise authority upon any social group that is unwilling to remain under this authority (excluding inmates). Therefore, any group has the right to secede, and the central authority may not try to force the seceding entity to remain within the state, even if the secessions would lead to the end of the larger state.

For example, the Union had no right to wage war against the Confederation in attempt to enforce the integrity of the U.S.A.; the Basques and the Scottish should be granted independence; the Polish-Lithuanian Commonwealth had no right to fight the Cossacks as they did, instead they should have granted the Cossacks independence, and limit themselves to defending their new, shrunken borders against the Cossack raids. Note that it is not my intend to discuss these particular examples, I am providing them only to help understand the main issue.

These claims were made by a Catholic priest and were backed up by some ecumenical council (sadly I don’t remember which one), which allegedly stated that each nation has the right to self-determination or even to have it’s one state (again, sadly I don’t remember the details here). Additionally, these opinions seem to be backed up by [CCC 1901](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG0015/__P6J.HTM), which states: “*If authority belongs to the order established by God, "the choice of the political regime and the appointment of rulers are left to the free decision of the citizens."*” – with a footnote directing to “*GS 74 # 3.*”

Does the Catholic Church really teach that every group has the right to secede whenever it wishes so? Does it forbid forceful attempts to prevent such secession in any case? Are there any official documents on the matter?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview of what this site is about, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). Interesting question! It would be helpful if you (or someone else reading this) could track down the specific Catholic priest and ecumenical council that you're referring to. Meanwhile, we'll see what answers come.

Comment: Bl. Pope Pius IX wrote [a letter to Jefferson Davies](http://catholicknight.blogspot.com/2009/02/pope-pius-ix-and-confederacy.html?m=1), acknowledging him as "Honorable President of the Confederate States of America."

Comment: It would appear that the official document is *Gaudium et Spes* (one of the output of Vatican II).

Comment: @AndrewLeach The CCC I referenced in my question links to Gaudium et Spes, but while I’m not certain, I can’t shake off the feeling that this priest was referring to a different council.

Comment: @Geremia Bl. Pope Pius IX authored the famous Syllabus of Errors, where he condemns, among others, that “it is lawful to refuse obedience to legitimate princes, and even to rebel against them” and cites «Encyclical "Qui pluribus," Nov. 9, 1864; Allocution "Quibusque vestrum," Oct. 4, 1847; "Noscitis et Nobiscum," Dec. 8, 1849; Apostolic Letter "Cum Catholica."»

Comment: @Geremia Sorry, I forgot to mention the source. Syllabus of Errors point 63, full text http://www.ewtn.com/library/PAPALDOC/P9SYLL.HTM

Comment: Perhaps an answer with some possible historical papal actions could be found in order to support any existing documents would be welcome. Can we find the reasons and/or any papal statements to back up various coronations such as Pepin  the Short or Charlemagne? In days gone by, Popes have even placed interdicts on various regions in order to bring  Catholic monarchs back to the moral code of the day, Hilaire Belloc as an historian has written on the subject of English succession and why he thinks it is invalid.

Comment: @gaazkam Yes, of course rebellion is a sin (cf. Eph. 6), but notice the Bl. Pope Pius IX says "*legitimate* princes." Some have lost their authority by enacting laws contrary to the natural or divine laws.

Comment: @Geremia That’s interesting. Many thanks so far. There are, however, two more problems. Q1. How does this relate to the already cited CCC 1901? These two documents seem to contradict each other on the matter. Q2. Assuming that a ruler did not loose their authority and therefore rebelling against them is sinful, but a rebellion still breaks out and it’s only goal is to secede, does the Church permit such a ruler to forcibly crush such a rebellion?

Comment: In passing: "the Scottish should be granted Independence". You mean forced to be independent against their wishes, as expressed in a referendum?

Comment: @gaazkam I will point out Stalin's question "The Pope! How many divisions has he got?" regarding whether or not the Pope, or the church has the combined authority, will, and means to "permit" or "not permit" a ruler forcibly crushing such a rebellion.  Since about 1870, and IMO about a century earlier, that has been a moot point.  The Church can always make its appeal to virtues and God's law, and does so with some frequency even nowadays.

Answer (score 4):

The morality of secession is related to the [tyrannicide](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/15108a.htm) (killing of tyrants) thesis of the Spanish scholastic Jesuit [Fr. Juan de Mariana](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/09659b.htm), ch. 5 of his *De Rege*.

The economist [Jesús Huerta de Soto](http://www.jesushuertadesoto.com), who specializes in Spanish scholasticism, describes Fr. De Mariana's thesis in his article "[Juan de Mariana and the Spanish Scholastics](http://www.jesushuertadesoto.com/articulos/articulos-en-ingles/juan-de-mariana-and-the-spanish-scholastics/#siete)" (cf. [his related lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u_j04HaR9Ak)):

> Although Father Juan de Mariana wrote many books, the first one with a libertarian content was, perhaps, the book entitled *De rege et regis institutione* (“*On the King and the Royal Institution*”) published in 1598, in which he set forth his famous defence of tyrannicide. According to Mariana any individual citizen can justly assassinate a king who imposes taxes without the people’s consent, seizes the property of individuals and squanders it, or prevents a meeting of a democratic parliament.⁷ The doctrines contained in this book were apparently used to justify the assassination of the French tyrant kings Henry III and Henry IV and the book was burned in Paris by the executioner as a result of a decree issued by the Parliament of Paris on July 4, 1610.⁸
>
> In Spain, although the authorities were not enthusiastic about it, the book was respected. In fact, all Mariana did was to take the idea that natural law is morally superior to the might of the state to its logical conclusion. This idea had previously been developed in detail by the great founder of international law, the Dominican Francisco de Vitoria (1485-1546), who began the Spanish scholastic tradition of denouncing the conquest and particularly the enslavement of the Indians by the Spaniards in the New World.
>
> Notes
> ⁷Mariana describes the tyrant as follows:
>
> > <sup>He seizes the property of individuals and squanders it, impelled as he is by the unkingly vices of lust, avarice, cruelty, and fraud … Tyrants, indeed, try to injure and ruin everybody, but they direct their attack especially against rich and upright men throughout the realm. They consider the good more suspect than the evil; and the virtue which they themselves lack is most formidable to them … They expel the better men from the commonwealth on the principle that whatever is exalted in the kingdom should be laid low … They exhaust all the rest so that they can not unite by demanding new tributes from them daily, by stirring up quarrels among the citizens, and by joining war to war. They build huge works at the expense and the suffering of the citizens. Whence the pyramids of Egypt were born … The tyrant necessarily fears that those whom he terrorizes and holds as slaves will attempt to overthrow him … Thus he forbids the citizens to congregate together, to meet in assemblies, and to discuss the commonwealth altogether, taking from them by secret-police methods the opportunity of free speaking and freely listening so that they are not even allowed to complain freely.
> > —Murray N. Rothbard, *[Economic Thought before Adam Smith](https://mises.org/library/austrian-perspective-history-economic-thought)*, op. cit., pp. 118-119.</sup>
>
> <sup>⁸See Juan de Mariana, *Discurso de las enfermedades de la Compañía, imprenta de Don Gabriel Ramírez, calle de Barrionuevo*, Madrid, año de 1768, “Dissertation on the author, and the legitimacy of this discourse”, p. 53.</sup>

An interesting part of [Prof. Huerta de Soto's lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u_j04HaR9Ak) (@[17:54](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u_j04HaR9Ak#t=17m54s)):

> But Mariana insists on another very important idea. He says natural law is vastly superior to the power of each king or ruler. This is an essential idea that is still perfectly applicable today. I believe that we must be aware of and very proud of the fact that when Thomas Jefferson, the founding father of the United States, was considering whether or not to rise up against the king of England, in order to give encouragement to Madison and the rest of the founding fathers of the great American homeland, he says to them: "You only have to read one book: *The History of Spain* by Fr. Juan de Mariana." And, in fact, [Madison even sent him a copy of the book](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Letter_to_James_Madison_-_September_1,_1785) [vol. 2; here's [a scan of Madison's copy on Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/historiagenerald02mari)], because it is a history of Spain written from the perspective of freedom, unmasking the tyrants.

---

It indeed is Catholic teaching that natural law is superior to human law. For the relationship between Divine, natural, and human law, see St. Thomas Aquinas's Treatise on Law ([*Summa Theologica* I-II qq. 90](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FS.html#TOC09)-108).

---

Also, see the article "[The Shipwreck of Secession](http://www.returntoorder.org/2016/07/shipwreck-secession/)" by Catholic author John Horvat II

Comment: Thank you for your answer. `or prevents a meeting of a democratic parliament` – does this mean that the Church considers systems such as mediaval feudalism and hereditary monarchies as immoral per se?

Comment: @gaazkam Fr. Mariana's view is not meant to be an official teaching of the the Church, nor does it seem to oppose Church teaching.

Comment: @gaazkam "*the Church considers systems such as mediaval feudalism and hereditary monarchies as immoral per se?*" No, quite the contrary; Pope Pius VI, for example, said monarchy is the best form of government ("*[praestantioris monorchici regiminis forma](http://nobility.org/2011/01/06/monarchy-republic-and-religion/)*") in principle.

Comment: How is Pope Pius VI's claim supposed to go with CCC 1901, which states: “If authority belongs to the order established by God, "the choice of the political regime and the appointment of rulers are left to the free decision of the citizens."” – with a footnote directing to “GS 74 # 3.”?

Comment: @gaazkam Pope Pius VI is not saying monarchy *must* be the form of civil government, but that it is the *best*.

Comment: I get it, but the problem is that CCC 1901 seems to me to say that democracy is the only form of civil government that does not oppose God. Also we have CCC 1904 which states that “It is preferable that each power be balanced by other powers and by other spheres of responsibility which keep it within proper bounds. This is the principle of the 'rule of law,' in which the law is sovereign and not the arbitrary will of men.” and this canon seems to outright claim that absolute monarchy is sub-optimal.

Comment: @gaazkam 1901 begins: "If authority belongs to the order established by God…" It is always true that God is the origin of civil power (cf. Pope Leo XIII's encyclical "On the Origin of Civil Power," [_Diuturnum_](https://w2.vatican.va/content/leo-xiii/en/encyclicals/documents/hf_l-xiii_enc_29061881_diuturnum.html)). 1904 appears to be a statement of the Catholic [principle of subsidiarity](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=36679) (i.e., that superiors do not meddle in the affairs that their subjects can deal with themselves).

Comment: Many thanks for your responses so far, really. If I may, though, I'd like to dwell on the subject a little bit more :) Rephrasing 1901: `If the choice of the political regime and the appointment of rulers are not left to the free decision of the citizens, then authority does not belong to the order established by God`. Assuming, for the sake of argument, that leaving the choice of the political regime and the appointment of rules to the free decisions of citizens is the definition of democracy, CCC 1901 blatantly states that any non-democratic system is ungodly. Is this interpretation correct?

Comment: @gaazkam Your "rephrasing" is really the converse of the original statement, and converses are not always the same as what they are the converse of. For example: "If it rains, then the sidewalk is wet." is not the same as to say: "If the sidewalk is wet, then it rains."

Comment: Your example with the rain proves that "if A then B" is not equivalent to "if B then A". But my transformation was a little bit different: rephrasing CCC 1901 I followed the law that "if A then B" is equivalent to "if not B then not A". So I'm sorry, but I think that my conversion was correct, while yours was, of course, not.

Comment: @gaazkam Sorry, I glossed over that you negate "A" and "B." Yes, you might be correct. When in doubt, stick with clear teaching like that expressed in [*Diuturnum*](https://w2.vatican.va/content/leo-xiii/en/encyclicals/documents/hf_l-xiii_enc_29061881_diuturnum.html).

Comment: So, I read Diuturnum. And it seems to me to contradict CCC 1902, which says: “A human law has the character of law to the extent that it accords with right reason, and thus derives from the eternal law. Insofar as it falls short of right reason it is said to be an unjust law, and thus has not so much the nature of law as of a kind of violence.” Which document has greater authority in case of incongruence: an encyclical, or the CCC?

Comment: In addition, Diuturnum seems to also be contradicted by CCC 2243, which says: “Armed resistance to oppression by political authority is not legitimate, unless all the following conditions are met: 1) there is certain, grave, and prolonged violation of fundamental rights; 2) all other means of redress have been exhausted; 3) such resistance will not provoke worse disorders; 4) there is well-founded hope of success; and 5) it is impossible reasonably to foresee any better solution.”

Comment: @gaazkam What exactly in _Diuturnum_ appears to contradict CCC 1902 or 2243?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Well, for me the key to understanding Diuturnum are the examples of the behaviour of Catholics in the Roman Empire, which Diuturnum seems to present as exemplary. CCC 1902 says that unjust or unreasonable law is a form of a violence rather than law, so we can conclude that we do not have to obey it; Diuturnum, however, doesn’t seem to provide such interpretation, instead it provides as exemplary the behaviour of early Christians who were abiding to unjust, unreasonable and obviously violence-like law… (continued)

Comment: …with the sole exception when such law was trying to make them commit a sin. So for me it seems that CCC 1902 permits disobedience in cases when Diuturnum condemns disobedience as sinful (namely, when the law is clearly unjust and unreasonable, yet it does not order it’s addressee to sin). The second incongruence is when CCC 2243 permits armed resistance to an unjust authority, yet Diuturnum praises early Christians for not resisting Roman Emperors. (continued)

Comment: It seems that Diuturnum, backing itself up with these examples, says that even if an authority is exercised by unjust and oppressive means, we have no right for resistance (with the sole exception for not obeying orders that try to make us sin – but even in such cases, not obeying that particular order seems to be everything that is permitted, and no matter how oppressive and unjust an authority is, no further actions against it are permitted). CCC 2243 seems to be saying otherwise.

Comment: @gaazkam Were Christians the majority in ancient Rome? If not, it's hard to see how condition #4 of CCC 2243 could hold. In Mexico during the [Cristiada](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1566501/), Pope Pius XI forbade an armed uprising of Catholics against their [Freemasonic](http://modernism.us.to/cristeros.html) oppressors, which resulted in more martyrs than in all the rest of the Americas combined. Pope Pius XI deeply regretted this;* he then gave Catholics permission to resist with arms.

Comment: *{cf. Pope Pius XI's encyclical "on the persecution of the Church in Mexico," [_Iniquis Afflictisque_](https://w2.vatican.va/content/pius-xi/en/encyclicals/documents/hf_p-xi_enc_18111926_iniquis-afflictisque.html) (1926): "…in narrating this We can scarcely keep back Our tears, some of these young men and boys have gladly met death, the rosary in their hands and the name of Christ King on their lips."}

Answer (score 3):

In the fascinating article "[Catholic Sources and the Declaration of Independence](https://web.archive.org/web/20140711211920/http://catholiceducation.org/articles/politics/pg0003.html)," Rev. John C. Rager, S.T.D., lists some parallels between the U.S.'s Declaration of Independence and St. Robert Bellarmine's and St. Thomas Aquinas's thought. Regarding "The right to change the government," he writes:

> Declaration of Independence: “Whenever any form of government becomes destructive of these ends, it is the right of the people to alter or abolish it, and to institute a new government...Prudence, indeed, will dictate that governments long established should not be changed for light and transient reasons.”
>
> Bellarmine: “For legitimate reasons the people can change the government to an aristocracy or a democracy or vice versa” (“De Laicis,” c. 6). “The people never transfers its powers to a king so completely but that it reserves to itself the right of receiving back this power” (*Recognitio de Laicis*, c. 6).
>
> St Thomas: “If any society of people have a right of choosing a king, then the king so established can be deposed by them without injustice, or his power can be curbed, when by tyranny he abuses his regal power” ([“De Rege et Regno,” Bk. I, c. 6](https://isidore.co/aquinas/DeRegno.htm#6)).

Comment: Would it make more sense to incorporate this answer into your previous one?

Comment: @Nathaniel It looks to me like two different answers approaching the same question from different angles and different teachings/authority